# Why order by year is not working?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table called Events and these are example of `EndDate` columns:

[image]

I am trying to extract months from these events, but I want them to be like: `11, 12, 1` (11 and 12 from current year, and 1 is from next year - 2013).

```
var ev = db.Events.Select(d => new { Month = d.StartDate.Value.Month, 
                                     EndDate = d.EndDate })
                  .Where(d => (d.EndDate >= DateTime.Now
                           || (   d.EndDate.Value.Day == DateTime.Now.Day 
                               && d.EndDate.Value.Month >= DateTime.Now.Month) ))
                  .OrderBy(d => d.EndDate.Value.Year)
                  .Select(d => new { Month = d.Month }).Distinct();
```

Well, I don't understand why this query does not work. It extracts months as: `1, 11, 12` which of course, is not what I want...

Ps: You can ignore `where` clause, that is only filtering the events from `now on`.

Comment: Try removing the first "Select" and see if that changes anything

Comment: You're ordering by the end date but selecting the start date, which probably doesn't help.

Comment: @Mihai it does not change the results..

Comment: @Rawling I forgot to say that `StartDate` and `EndDate` are the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sorting on Year only `.OrderBy(d => d.EndDate.Value.Year)` but you probably want to sort by `d.EndDate.Value`

Year only will be ignoring any days/months part of the date...so the "first" 2012 in the list is the first item.

```
    var events = new List<DateTime>
    {
        new DateTime(2013,11,1),
        new DateTime(2013,5,1),
        new DateTime(2013,4,1),
        new DateTime(2012,12,29),
        new DateTime(2012,12,28)
    };

    var ev = events.Select(d => new { Month = d.Month, Date = d })
        .Where(d => (d.Date >= DateTime.Now || (d.Date.Day == DateTime.Now.Day && d.Date.Month >= DateTime.Now.Month)))
        .OrderBy(d => d.Date.Year)
        .Select(d => new { Month = d.Month })
        .Distinct();
```

will return `12,11,5,4`

```
var ev = events.Select(d => new { Month = d.Month, Date = d })
                .Where(d => (d.Date >= DateTime.Now || (d.Date.Day == DateTime.Now.Day && d.Date.Month >= DateTime.Now.Month)))
                .OrderBy(d => d.Date)
                .Select(d => new { Month = d.Month })
                .Distinct();
```

will return `12,4,5,11`

Comment: Thanks, it works for your examples but no longer when I use my db. I even tried first to make a list of events from db like you did: `var eventsFromDb = db.Events.Select(d => d.EndDate.Value);` and to apply your query to this list and it's not working... This is very strange.

Comment: But it works if I do like `foreach (DateTime dateVal in eventsFromDb)
        {
            events.Add(dateVal);
        }`... unbelievable... (so if I move results from db into a list and filter on that list like you did.

Comment: To debug the original from the database use SQL Server Profiler to check the actual query and the order of the original returned items.  The select statement generated might not be quite what you expect.  *I THINK you can also change to "db.Events.AsEnumerable()....., but check that first!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be it, but I see nothing in the documentation for `Enumerable.Distinct()` that guarantees results in any given order. You might like to re-jig your query to check whether this is the case or not.

Comment: It does in fact return them in order, although you're correct in that the documentation specifically notes that it doesn't so there's no guarantee it'll continue to return them in order in future \o/

Answer (score 1):

Change the Order statement to:

> .OrderBy(d => d.EndDate.Value.Year).ThenBy(d =>
>   d.EndDate.Value.Month)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an enumeration of dates and want to get just the month numbers, in order, you can do the following:

```
var months = dates
    .Select(d => new { Month = d.Month, Year = d.Year })
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(a => 12 * d.Year + d.Month)
    // or .OrderBy(a => a.Year).ThenBy(a => a.Month)
    .Select(a => a.Month);
```

Note the `Distinct` call *before* you get rid of the year means e.g. `1/1/2011, 5/5/2011, 1/1/2012` will return `1, 5, 1` which I assume is what you want.

You can just append this query to your list of filtered dates; you'll need to give it a list of *dates* though, not a list of whatever anonymous object you're constructing at the moment.